# How to edit plugin to use the theme's template files

Tags: templates, wordpress

I am using a theme called Hemingway, it's a great theme with three page layouts. (full-width, with sidebar, without sidebar). This is all working great. I can choose one of three options in page settings.

[image: Page layout template]

I'm also using the Projects plugin by Woothemes. This plugin makes it easy to add recent projects with a photo gallery and some other options. It's working when I'm using the shortcode:

```
[projects limit="12" columns="2" orderby="date" order="desc" exclude_categories=""]
```

I'm using this shortcode with two columns on a full-width template. This is working great, but when I'm trying to use the functionality to automatically add the content of projects to the page using the option built-in Projects:
[image: projects settings]
The full-width template is not working and the sidebar is shown. Also the two column layout for projects is not working. They just aligned beneath eachother.

---

### **How it should look like (this example is with shortcodes):**

http://hoveniersbedrijfameland.nl/projecten/

### **How it looks with the option in projects to choose a page: (this is wrong)**

http://hoveniersbedrijfameland.nl/projects/

---

How can I debug this to see what breaks it?

### **What I tried so far:**

1. I've tried the plugin to behave like I want. This means, that the
   plugin will use the full page template for 'categories' instead of
   using the archive page. I don't really know how the plugin is build,
   so it's hard to eit the right file.
2. I've tried a workaround with url routing, but this isn't the best
   approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. I copied the archive-project.php file to my theme and edited the content with the ones in the full-width template. I need to style it myself because the pages are broken if I leave it like that.

If I want to edit page template now, I need to code it in the ffile instead of choosing it from the pages > page layout in the admin panel.
I'll fix that later.

FINAL UPDATE: I hardcoded everything and it's working for me now. I don't need any further help, I'm now looking into the custom post types to change the content template.